# How to add more than one image in blog using django

Tags: python, django

I'm creating my blog using Django. I want to add images in between the post. For this, I'm using 5 image field in one model.

I have tried to add `<img src=" {{article.img1.url}} "</img>` in the content of the article, still it's not showing images in between my written article.

This is my template code,

models.py

```
class article_by_author(models.Model):
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='xxxx')
    article_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    article_content = models.TextField(max_length=999999, default='')
    article_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    article_category = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    article_priority = models.IntegerField()
    article_category_priority = models.IntegerField()
    article_views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    author_img = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='images/')
    article_img = models.ImageField(blank=False, upload_to='article_img/')
    img1 = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='article_img/')
    img2 = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='article_img/')
    img3 = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='article_img/')
    img4 = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='article_img/')
    img5 = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='article_img/')
```

this is my Template,

```
{% for article in full_article %}
<div id="post-header" class="page-header">
    <div class="background-img" style="background-image: url('{{article.article_img.url }}');"></div>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="post-meta">
            <a class="post-category cat-2" href="../../../preview/theme/webmag/category.html">{{article.article_category}}</a>
            <span class="post-date">{{article.article_date|stringformat:".10s"}}</span>
            </div>
            <h1>{{article.article_title}}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        </div>
<div class="main-post"> 
    {{article.article_content|safe}}
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

This is my view.py

```
full_article = article_by_author.objects.filter(article_title=article_title)
context = {
    'full_article':full_article,
}
```

For adding Content, I have another page with a form where I add all the article content. Now my question is how to call images(img1, img2,..) in between the article text I have written.

And if there is any other way to do this, please suggest.

Comment: Class names should follow the `UpperCaseCamelCase` convention

Answer (score 0):

You can show an image by doing

```
<img src="{{ article.img1.url }}">
```

Although you should have a better model than hard coding number of images since img2.url will throw an error if only 1 image was uploaded. Or you can use if statements to check if the image exists and only then show it

```
{% if article.img2 %}
   <img src="{{ article.img2.url }}">
{% endif %}
```

So with your current model structure, this is your best bet:

```
{% if article.img1 %}
   <img src="{{ article.img1.url }}">
{% endif %}
{% if article.img2 %}
   <img src="{{ article.img2.url }}">
{% endif %}
{% if article.img3 %}
   <img src="{{ article.img3.url }}">
{% endif %}
{% if article.img4 %}
   <img src="{{ article.img4.url }}">
{% endif %}
{% if article.img5 %}
   <img src="{{ article.img5.url }}">
{% endif %}
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but how to write this above code in between my blog/article content, i mean i am taking raw input from a form, and save that content to my database, and on my article page, i just print that content. I have tried to put <img src="{{ article.img1.url }}"> this is my content, but it's not rendering it. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to update the model and also follow pep8 standard. a many-to-one relationship, are usually handled by making a separate model for the many and, in that model, using a ForeignKey to the "one".

```
class PostPicture(models.Model):
    picture = models.ImageField(related_name='images',upload_to='blog/post_pics', blank=True)
    postid = models.ForeignKey('Post')


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    userid = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='userblogpost')
    PostPicture = None
```

Comment: Thank You for Your response. I have tried this, didn't work for me, my problem how to put this pictures in between my written post/article.